# Search for implementation of Faster RCNN

Tags: classification, object-detection, implementation, open-source

What are the best written and best structured Faster RCNN implementations that you know? Please provide references.

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with Tensorflow, you can refer [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)`

you can find the architecture and implementation in the below codes,

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py

With feature extractors in implementation
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/models

Hope it helps.